# How to set different colors of TextInputLayout's boxBackground?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I have a simple input field using the `TextInputLayout`. I can set the box background color with

```
setBoxBackgroundColorResource(R.color.mycolor)
```

But now I would like to have different colors depending on state. `mycolor_activated` for activated state, and `mycolor_default` for detault state. Creating a color state list and setting it as the resource does not work, it ignores the activated state:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="#FFF" />
    <item android:color="#000" />
</selector>
```

```
setBoxBackgroundColorResource(R.color.myselector)
```

Is there a way to do this? I don't have problems setting color state list for stroke for example. Please note that I also need to set the `TextInputLayout`'s properties programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method **`setBoxBackgroundColorStateList`**.

```
textInputLayout.setBoxBackgroundColorStateList(
         ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.my_selector));
```

**Note:** this method requires at least the version `1.2.0-beta01`

It is the default selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="...." android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="..." android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="..." android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="..."/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I see, that was my issue, I was using `1.2.0-alpha01`. Thanks!